# Determine if Decimal, Fraction or Invalid using Regex

Tags: java, regex

How can I determine the input of the user if it is **decimal,fraction,mixed** fraction or invalid?

This is the input that is allowed on my program

```
String[] s = new String[]{ "0",".",".0",".01","1.","1.0","1.01", "1 ","1 1","1/2","1/","1/0", "1 1/1", "1 0/0","1 /","1 /0", "1 0/"};
```

**expected output:**

```
0) 0  ----  Zero

1) .  ----  Error

2) .0  ----  Zero

3) 0.01  ----   Decimal

4) 1.  ----  Decimal(the input 1. should be turned to decimal)

5) 1.0  ----   Decimal

6) 1.01  ----   Decimal

7) 1   ----  Decimal(the input with space after the whole number must be decimal)

8) 1 1  ----  Error(because of the space between the 1)

9) 1/2  ----  Fraction

10) 1/  ----  Error

11) 1/0  ----  Error

12) 1 1/1  ----  Mixed Fraction

13) 1 0/0  ----  Error

14) 1 /  ----  Error

15) 1 /0  ----  Error

16) 1 0/  ----  Error
```

**Actual Output:**

```
0) 0  ----  Zero

1) .  ----  Error

2) .0  ----  Zero

3) 0.01  ----   Decimal

4) 1.  ----  Error

5) 1.0  ----   Decimal

6) 1.01  ----   Decimal

7) 1   ----  Error

8) 1 1  ----  Mixed Fraction

9) 1/2  ----  Fraction

10) 1/  ----  Fraction

11) 1/0  ----  Fraction

12) 1 1/1  ----  Mixed Fraction

13) 1 0/0  ----  Error

14) 1 /  ----  Error

15) 1 /0  ----  Error

16) 1 0/  ----  Error
```

I don't have much knowledge on how to build a good pattern of regex?

my code:

```
public class DecimalOrFraction {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String[] s = new String[]{ "0",".",".0",".01","1.","1.0","1.01", "1 ","1 1","1/2","1/","1/0", "1 1/1", "1 0/0","1 /","1 /0", "1 0/"};

        for (int x = 0 ;x<s.length;x++) {
            if(s[x].matches("[0]?([.][0]{1,3}\\s{0,1})?")){
                System.out.println(x+") "+s[x]+"  ----  Zero"); 
            }
            else if(s[x].matches("\\d{0,3}([.]\\d{1,3}\\s{0,1})?")){
                System.out.println(x+") "+Float.valueOf(s[x])+"  ----   Decimal");
            }
            else if(s[x].matches("[1-9]{1,5}([.]\\d{1,3})?\\s[1-9]\\d{0,2}([/]\\d{0,3})?")){
                System.out.println(x+") "+s[x]+"  ----  Mixed Fraction");
            }
            else if(s[x].matches("[1-9]\\d{0,4}[/]\\d{0,3}")){
                System.out.println(x+") "+s[x]+"  ----  Fraction");
            } 
            else{
                System.out.println(x+") "+s[x]+"  ----  Error");    
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Masud I included my codes on my post

Comment: Sheesh, there are even more mismatches between the given values and the code. Please fix.

Comment: @owlstead sorry I updated the given values

Comment: I like the fact that you at least split up the regex yourself already. I would split it up a bit more though. Normally you simply remove whitespace from beginning/end before you start. Natural numbers are easy to test for, so do that before trying the decimals. `{0,1}` is normally not used, as it is identical to using `?`. Finally, split up *syntactical* and *semantical* errors (such as division by zero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show what you can do when you split up the function in multiple parts I've created some code. Note that this not constitute a clear (class) design.

This code has the advantages that you can actually *do* something with the values ones you parsed them. It is also useful to give good error messages. If you split up the `main` method even more, you can create a parser that validates values in real time as well (useful if you want to validate values within a GUI, for instance).

```
public class Numbers {

private static final String[] s = new String[]{ "0",".",".0",".01","1.","1.0","1.01", "1 ","1 1","1/2","1/","1/0", "1 1/1", "1 0/0","1 /","1 /0", "1 0/"};

    private static final Pattern FRACTION_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?:(\\d+)\\s+)?(\\d+)/(\\d+)");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (String value : s) {
            counter++;
            String trimmedValue = value.trim();
            if (isNumber(trimmedValue)) {
                System.out.printf("%d) %s ---- Natural number%n", counter, trimmedValue);
                continue;
            }

            boolean parseDecimal = isProbablyDecimal(trimmedValue);
            boolean parseFraction = isProbablyFraction(trimmedValue);

            if (parseDecimal && parseFraction) {
                System.out.printf("%d) %s ---- Error (both decimal & fraction)%n", counter, trimmedValue);
                continue;
            }

            if (parseDecimal) {
                if (!trimmedValue.matches("\\d*[.]\\d+")) {
                    System.out.printf("%d) %s ---- Error (invalid decimal)%n", counter, trimmedValue);
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.printf("%d) %s ---- Decimal value%n", counter, trimmedValue);
                continue;
            }

            if (parseFraction) {
                Matcher m = FRACTION_PATTERN.matcher(trimmedValue);
                if (!m.matches()) {
                    System.out.printf("%d) %s ---- Error (invalid faction)%n", counter, trimmedValue);
                    continue;
                }
                if (Integer.valueOf(m.group(3)) == 0) {
                    System.out.printf("%d) %s ---- Error (division by zero in fraction)%n", counter, trimmedValue);
                    continue;
                }
                if (m.group(1) != null) {
                    System.out.printf("%d) %s ---- Mixed fraction%n", counter, trimmedValue);
                    continue;
                }

                System.out.printf("%d) %s ---- Fraction%n", counter, trimmedValue);
                continue;
            }

            System.out.printf("%d) %s ---- Error (Cannot make bread out of it)%n", counter, trimmedValue);
            continue;

        }
    }

    public static boolean isNumber(String value) {
        return value.matches("\\d+");
    }

    public static boolean isProbablyDecimal(String value) {
        // note, some countries use comma instead of dot
        return value.contains(".");
    }

    public static boolean isProbablyFraction(String value) {
        return value.contains("/");
    }
}
```

The output:

```
1) 0 ---- Natural number
2) . ---- Error (invalid decimal)
3) .0 ---- Decimal value
4) .01 ---- Decimal value
5) 1. ---- Error (invalid decimal)
6) 1.0 ---- Decimal value
7) 1.01 ---- Decimal value
8) 1 ---- Natural number
9) 1 1 ---- Error (Cannot make bread out of it)
10) 1/2 ---- Fraction
11) 1/ ---- Error (invalid faction)
12) 1/0 ---- Error (division by zero in fraction)
13) 1 1/1 ---- Mixed fraction
14) 1 0/0 ---- Error (division by zero in fraction)
15) 1 / ---- Error (invalid faction)
16) 1 /0 ---- Error (invalid faction)
17) 1 0/ ---- Error (invalid faction)
```

Comment: Hint, you could also create a `Result` class, possibly with a `ResultType` enum with the values `RATIONAL`, `DECIMAL`, `FRACTION`, `MIXED_FRACTION` and - of course - `ERROR`. Normally you don't use exceptions for user input.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
`\d+\.\d+|\d+\.$|^.0$|\d+/[1-9]+|\d+ \d+/[1-9]+`

Answer (score 0):

This returns the correct values for your examples:

```
^(\d*\.?\d*)\s?(\d+/[1-9]\d*)?$
```

[Working example on RegExr](http://regexr.com?37epo)

In Java it would be: `^(\\d*\\.?\\d*)\\s?(\\d+/[1-9]\\d*)?$`

Comment: I like this answer except that it allows 2.2/2 to pass.  How can that be fixed? @OGhaza